# Carousel Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Esta aplicado el css que aporto **qwerty** y queda de esa manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .display-4 {
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
  }
  h4 {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <!-- Archivos Personales -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/css/main.css">

        <title>Madiweb</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Menu Principal -->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-5 mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empresa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Barra Contacto -->
                <span class="navbar-text mr-5 text-body">
                    (+54) 03725 - 15440397 | info@madiweb.com
                </span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Portada -->
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://td2branding.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Fondo-Amco-1920-x-800-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="portada-1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
                        <div class="display-4">DISEÑO WEB A MEDIDA</div>
                        <hr class="my-2 bg-white">
                        <h4>Somos diseñadores de web, analizamos cada proyecto y presentamos la mejor opción para cada necesidad, brindando sitios funcionales de calidad.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, falta mucha información y no nos brindas el resultado en un dispositivo como en el que tienes problemas. Editalo y muestranos una imagen de como se ve en en un dispositivo "chico" y como debería verse según tu criterio.

Comment: Ya esta editado Victor, disculpa

Comment: @AlejandroParcellier estaría bien que volvieras a editar tu pregunta, eliminaste la descripción de tu problema y por ende el sentido de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Basta con poner un @media, modifica en font size de el elemento y es importante que le pongas !important para que aplique.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .display-4 {
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
  }
  h4 {
  font-size: 1em !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Madiweb</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Menu Principal -->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-5 mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Empresa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Barra Contacto -->
                <span class="navbar-text mr-5 text-body">
                    (+54) 03725 - 15440397 | info@madiweb.com
                </span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Portada -->
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://td2branding.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Fondo-Amco-1920-x-800-1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="portada-1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
                        <div class="display-4">DISEÑO WEB A MEDIDA</div>
                        <hr class="my-2 bg-white">
                        <h4>Somos diseñadores de web, analizamos cada proyecto y presentamos la mejor opción para cada necesidad, brindando sitios funcionales de calidad.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sacame una duda.. si estoy usando bootstrap, acaso no es que se adapta solo el responsive?

Comment: El diseño responsivo no adapta tamaños de letra, solo su disposicion en el contenedor en el que se encuentra. por eso es mejor configurarlo independientemente. otra opcion tambien es cambiar el h4 por un h6. y editar al hr con un my-1.

Comment: No se que hago mal que ninguno de los 2 me toma... agregue el @media pero no hace el mismo efecto. en si no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Agregaste tal cual el código, con el !important?

Comment: ¿Porque no editas la pregunta y insertas el código de nuevo?

Comment: Listo funciono.. volvi a sobreescribir el codigo html de aca y lo tomo.

Comment: Siempre vas a tener problemas ya que si es mucho texto y el contenedor pequeño entonces es complicado de visualizar todo el contenido. Ahí si tienes que cambir su tamaño por una medida mucho más pequeña

Comment: Si eso es lo que estoy viendo... que no entra todo el contenido modifico la respuesta asi ven como quedo

Comment: Ya lo logre... gracias por el aporte. Victor me sacaste de una duda grande con respecto al responsive de BS.